# ¿Como crear varios dropdown options en flet sin utilizar for dentro de options (no lo permite)?

Tags: python, bucle-for, app, dropdown, flet

El código así funciona pero, a la vista, esta muy mal hecho (hay 75 elementos). El `for` dentro de `options=`, no es viable porque no lo permite, intente usar una listview y tampoco, creo que es un vacío del framework.

```
patent_txt = ft.Dropdown(
    label="Patente",
    options=[                               
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[0]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[1]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[2]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[3]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[4]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[5]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[6]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[7]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[8]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[9]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[10]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[11]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[12]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[13]),
        ft.dropdown.Option(lista_patentes[14]),
        ])
```

Comment: Probaste con crear una lista vacía, usar un for que cree los 75 Option y los agregue a dicha, y pasar la variable que contiene la lista como argumento de DropDown? Algo como ft.Dropdown(options=mi_lista_de_opciones_llenada_con_un_for)

Comment: Si decis asi, me tira error este error, 'list' object has no attribute '_build_add_commands'

Comment: Esto puse dentro del for
lista_opciones.append(ft.dropdown.Option(elemento))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes tener ningún problema en usar un `for`, se supone que options debe recibir una lista, por lo que puedes usar una lista por compresión asi:

```
options = [ft.dropdown.Option(patente) for patente in lista_patentes]
```

aunque de hecho cualquier iterable de objetos `flet.dropdown.Option` será válido, por ejemplo un generador:

```
options = (ft.dropdown.Option(patente) for patente in lista_patentes)
```

o incluso puedes usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
options = map(ft.dropdown.Option, lista_patentes)
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import flet as ft


lista_patentes = range(15)

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Flet example"
    
    patent_txt = ft.Dropdown(
        label = "Patente",
        #options = (ft.dropdown.Option(patente) for patente in lista_patentes)
        options = map(ft.dropdown.Option, lista_patentes)
        )
    
    page.add(patent_txt)
 

ft.app(target=main)
```

---

Por el error que comentas supongo que estas haciendo algo como esto:

```
lista_opciones = []
for elemento in lista_patentes:
    lista_opciones.append(ft.dropdown.Option(elemento))
    
patent_txt = ft.Dropdown(
    label = "Patente",
    options = [lista_opciones]
    )
```

El problema es que `[lista_opciones]` es una lista de listas, debe ser simplemente:

```
lista_opciones = []
for elemento in lista_patentes:
    lista_opciones.append(ft.dropdown.Option(elemento))
    
patent_txt = ft.Dropdown(
    label = "Patente",
    options = lista_opciones
    )
```

Aunque usar compresión de generadores/listas o `map` es mas simple, menos código y algo mas eficiente incluso.

Comment: Buenisimo!! No se me habia ocurrido hacerlo en la misma linea el for, ese era el problema. Muchas gracias