# Cómo puedo rellenar un select/dropDown con datos de sqlite3 pero con el framework Flet

Tags: python, dropdown, flet

Este sería el pequeño fragmento de código donde se desea poner la información que trae la db

```
midlePanel = Container(
        content=Row(
            controls=[
                Dropdown(
                    width=100,
                    options=[
                        # esto lo llena la DB (Aqui van los grados)
                    ],
                )
            ]
        )
    )
```

Esta es la función que retorna los grupos de estudiantes de la base de datos

```
def getGradesFromDB():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('attendance.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grade FROM students')
    gradeList = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return gradeList
```

El resultado de lo que retorna la función anterior es algo así [(...)]. Una lista con una tupla con todos los grados disponibles

la iteración que hago para sacar cada grupo por separado es la siguiente

```
for grade, in getGradesFromDB():
    print(grade)
```

la idea es que por cada grupo iterado se agregue al dropDown de flet

Intente hacer un bucle for dentro del dropDonw (no funciono) me arrojaba un error

Comment: Hola ALEX, mírate esta pregunta y mi respuesta, debería solucionar tu duda: [¿Como crear varios dropdown options en flet sin utilizar for dentro de options (no lo permite)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/610639/15089). En tu caso, si tu forma de iterar para conseguir las cadenas de cada opción es correcta y no he pasado algo por alto, bastaría con  algo como `options=[ft.dropdown.Option(grade) for grade,  in getGradesFromDB()]`